# Wordpress multisite contact form 7 set up issues

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7, multisite

Having a headache with this one and I ‘think’ the issue is with Contact form 7, let me explain what is going on

I have a WordPress multisite, I am using WP Mail SMTP to send emails through this site – with this plugin I can send test emails which are received from each of the different sites in my WordPress multi site (just for some extra detail, the WP Mail SMTP plugin is installed in each of the sites plugins directory with the settings for the plugin set in each sites wp-config.php file as best practice for the plugin)

So I think the sites are set up and configured correctly as they can send the test email so I don’t think the issue is there, I have Contact Form 7 set up on each site and I can send emails through the root site but not from the other (there are only two sites on this Network) … as far as I can tell they’re set up identically

On the second site when I hit the ‘send’ button it just hangs and never sends … however in the console I am getting a warning I am not getting on the other site;

POST http://www.multisite.com/child/page/ 404 (Not Found)

404 on POST is confusing me .. I can’t see any files which are missing and all looks in order so that’s stumped me completely!

Feel free to try it out yourself, here is the working version on the parent root site

http://www.camp-site-finder.com/suggest-a-feature/

And the broken one

http://www.camp-site-finder.com/glamping/send-test/

(The site isn’t live so don’t worry about trying out sending etc)

If anyone could point me in the right direction or offer any advice on how I could debug this further I’d be hugely grateful!

Thank you in advance – hopefully that’s all the information you require

Comment: Small update

I've tried a few extra things - switching off all plugins, changing the theme ... but the bug was still present

However I've just updated the Contact Form 7 plugin to the latest (I was one behind) and the issue remains but behaves different

The emails are still not sending but instead of hanging forever the page reloads and I get a query string added to the URL - /#wpcf7-f92-p78-o1

Comment: seems to working fine.  Just tried it, managed to successfully submit on the form of your 2nd link

Answer (score 0):

the cf7 is now using WP built in REST api end-points to communicate with the server, your form is looking for the following end-point,

```
http://www.camp-site-finder.com/glamping/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/726/feedback
```

however, what can happen with some setups is that the htaccess file is redirecting requests by adding  closing '/' at the end and this breaks cf7's POST submission POST. resulting in a 404 error.  Many people have reported this [issue on the plugin support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/after-the-4-8-update-ajax-loader-and-error-messages-issue/page/5/), so check if this is also the issue with your setup.